# How does "static" garantee that there is only one instance of a class in the property?

Tags: java, thread-safety, singleton

The best example I have to demonstrate what I'm asking is the *Singleton* pattern

```
public class Singleton {     
     private static Singleton instance = new Singleton();     

     private Singleton() {     
     }     

     public static Singleton getInstance() {
          return instance;    
     } 
}
```

In this code, the static variable is introduce in order to avoid ANY needs to synchronization to acquiring a pointer to Singleton instance. There is a way to know how this happens? how static is implemented?

Comment: I'd still add `final` to guarantee safe publication. Also it's implemented in the class loading system - any static initialization code of the class has to run when the class is loaded, which happens the first time it's used in executing code. The class loader probably takes care of the appropriate synchronization to make sure no threads can see a half-initialised class.

Comment: Because it belongs to the class and not the object... see the selected answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18402564/how-do-static-methods-work

Comment: this can help http://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html.

Comment: Keep in mind that if the singleton has mutable state, changing this state after construction *does* require synchronization or similar thread-safe constructs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Static fields are initialized when the class is loaded, in such a way to prevent multiple threads from initializing them at the same time. See [JLS 12.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2) for details on how that works. In your code, nothing else ever sets the value of the `static` field after that class load, so the only value it'll have is the one instantiated at class load time.

You can/should make this clearer (and more future-proof in terms of code changes) by marking the field `final`. This is probably also needed for full thread safety according to the JLS (though that's actually [not a problem in practice](http://cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2013-June/011410.html)).

---

<sub>Slight self-nit: "Class loading" in the above paragraphs is actually "class instantiation," which is actually a step that happens *after* loading as defined by the JLS. I've called it "loading" to make it more obviously distinct from the static fields' instantiation. Even though class loading is only one step in the initialization of classes (as defined in JLS 12.4, link above), the whole process is sometimes shortened to "class loading" in common parlance.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Static properties of class are loaded during class is loaded by jvm, as this happens only once during run time. It is guaranteed that static properties are created only once.